# Repetitive Frequent Auto Downloads of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google

Why, pray tell, is Google Chrome downloaded for installation 3 or 4 times a week?  More often than Firefox, which also downloads frequently.

Comment: How did you install it? If you installed the dev version, you're getting the updates that come with the developer's/unstable version.

Answer (score 0):

Google has been pushing out a lot of new versions in the last week or so, not just for Ubuntu, but for the Windows world too.